# Coldfusion 9 sending duplicate emails

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

We recently upgraded from Coldfusion 8 to coldfusion 9. All the scheduled jobs now send emails multiple times. sometimes 2ce, 3ce, or even 4 times. Unistalled and re-installed CF. Still doesn't seem to work normally.Anyone had this issue/knows what to do?

Comment: Was the upgrade done on the same server or was it also a new server?  Guess what I am getting at is any chance those scheduled jobs are being called more than once and perhaps from more than one source?

Comment: It was done on the same server. That's what I think too. I'm just wondering what other source could be calling it.

Comment: You could add some code to the scheduled tasks that emails you a dump of the CGI scope.  Maybe from that could detect any differences in what is calling the tasks.  Also it would at least enable you to verify if it is the tasks being called more than once or something else causing duplicate emailing.

Comment: Last time that happened to us was because we had two instances of ColdFusion running.

Comment: How many ColdFusion processes have you got running? I suspect Dan is correct.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was running only one instance of Coldfusion.I resolved it by uninstalling IIS and re-installing it and also uninstalling CF9 and upgrading CF on the server.